# Sequential Execution in Apache Beam - Java SDK 2.18.0

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

Hi I have a couple of queries I want to run & save results in sequence one after another using Apache Beam, I've seen some similar questions but couldn't find an answer. I'm used to designing pipelines using Airflow and I'm fairly new to Apache Beam. I'm using the Dataflow runner. Here's my code right now: I would like query2 to run only after query1 results are saved to the corresponding table. How do I chain them?

```
    PCollection<TableRow> resultsStep1 = getData("Run Query 1",
            "Select * FROM basetable");

    resultsStep1.apply("Save Query1 data",
            BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
                    .withSchema(BigQueryUtils.toTableSchema(resultsStep1.getSchema()))
                    .to("resultsStep1")
                    .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
                    .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE)
    );

    PCollection<TableRow> resultsStep2 = getData("Run Query 2",
            "Select * FROM resultsStep1");

    resultsStep2.apply("Save Query2 data",
            BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
                    .withSchema(BigQueryUtils.toTableSchema(resultsStep2.getSchema()))
                    .to("resultsStep2")
                    .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED)
                    .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE)
    );
```

And here's my getData function definition:

```
private PCollection<TableRow> getData(final String taskName, final String query) {
    return pipeline.apply(taskName,
            BigQueryIO.readTableRowsWithSchema()
                    .fromQuery(query)
                    .usingStandardSql()
                    .withCoder(TableRowJsonCoder.of()));
}
```

**Edit (Update): Turns out:**
`You can’t sequence the completion of a BigQuery write with other steps of your pipeline.`

Which I think is a big limitation for designing pipelines.
Source: https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/#limitations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the `Wait` method to do this. A contrived example is below

```
 PCollection<Void> firstWriteResults = data.apply(ParDo.of(...write to first database...));
 data.apply(Wait.on(firstWriteResults))
     // Windows of this intermediate PCollection will be processed no earlier than when
     // the respective window of firstWriteResults closes.
     .apply(ParDo.of(...write to second database...));
```

You can find more details in the API documentation present here - https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.17.0/index.html?org/apache/beam/sdk/transforms/Wait.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jayadeep. I am able to connect two read tasks; i.e.: I can define Wait.on() between PCollection objects. Somehow my "write to bigquery" step doesn't return a PCollection<Void> and I'm unable to define the "write then read" dependency. If you have any ideas I'd appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: Good Suggestion, I didn't know about Wait. I was about to suggest a weird hack with an unnecessary GBK. This is a much better solution

Comment: @AlexAmato what weird hack were you going to suggest, I'm curious :)

Comment: In a batch pipeline everything that happens before and after a GBK happen on separate "stages" and a stage won't start until its inputs have been processed. So I was going to suggest making your BigQueryIO output to a GBK and have the next stage begin reading after that. But this would likely have required modifying source code since BigQueryIO.Read doesn't receive input elements and BigQueryIO.Write doesn't produce output elements.