# Apache Beam: Wait for AvroIO write step is done before start ImportTransform Dataflow template

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow

I'm using apache beam to create a pipeline where basically reads an InputFile, Convert to Avro, write the AvroFile to a bucket and then Import these avro files to Spanner using Dataflow template

The problem that I'm facing is that the last step (Import the Avro files to the Database) is starting before the previous (write Avro Files to the bucket) is done.

I tried to add the Wait.on function but that only works if returns a PCollection, but when I write the files to avro it returns PDone.

Example of the Code:

```java
// Step 1: Read Files
PCollection<String> lines = pipeline.apply("Reading Input Data exported from Cassandra",TextIO.read().from(options.getInputFile()));

// Step 2: Convert to Avro
lines .apply("Write Item Avro File",AvroIO.writeGenericRecords(spannerItemAvroSchema).to(options.getOutput()).withSuffix(".avro"));

// Step 3: Import to the DataBase

pipeline.apply( new ImportTransform(
                spannerConfig,
                options.getInputDir(),
                options.getWaitForIndexes(),
                options.getWaitForForeignKeys(),
                options.getEarlyIndexCreateFlag()));
```

Again, the problem is because step 3 starts before Step 2 is done

any ideas?

Comment: Hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60749099/sequential-execution-in-apache-beam-java-sdk-2-18-0

Comment: Thanks for reply Ricco, but that won't work since AvroIO.write function returns a PDone and it can't use Wait method. This method (Wait) only works if returns a PCollection

Answer (score 0):

This is a flaw in the API, see, e.g. a [recent discussion](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/r1fa3599ef9c0034d2bfa0614012bc864ce7b296228d8cf804c931065%40%3Cuser.beam.apache.org%3E) on this on the beam dev list. The only solutions for now are to either fork AvroIO to return a PCollection or run two pipelines sequentially.

Comment: That's exactly my problem. Thanks for sharing that